# Coriolis Acceleration and Latitude?

Tags: coriolis-effect

We had a lecture on the Coriolis effect today and I am very very confused, this is the first time I've heard of it as such. Anyway, I know that Coriolis acceleration is calculated by $\vec{a} = -2 \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}$ where $\vert \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}\vert = \omega v \sin\theta$. This gives $a = -2\omega v \sin \theta$. If I am given a latitude of say, 40°, how do I calculate the Coriolis acceleration of a moving object such as a bus in different directions like due south or due east?

Also, can I use $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ to calculate $\omega$? Would $T$ be the seconds in a day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the Coriolis acceleration is $$\vec{a} = -2 \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v},$$ or $$a =-2\omega v \sin \theta$$ then $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec v$, the vector of velocity and $\vec \omega$, the vector of angular velocity, which always points upwards.

So for example, when you're at the north pole and shoot an arrow horizontally to the earth's surface, $\theta$ is 90 degrees and since $sin(90)=1$, the  coriolis acceleration is $a=-2\omega v$.

When you go further in direction of the equator, the angle $\theta$ between the velocity vector and the angular velocity vector increases. At a latitude $\phi$, the angle $\theta$ these two vectors form is $180^\circ-\phi$:

[image]

Now you have to plug $\theta=180^\circ-\phi$ into the sine in $a = - 2\omega v \sin \theta$. The [trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) gives us

$$sin(180^\circ - \phi)=sin(180^\circ)cos(\phi)-cos(180^\circ)sin(\phi)=sin(\phi) $$ since sin(180°)=0 and cos(180°)=-1.

So at the end you simply have $$a =- 2\omega v \sin \phi$$ which tells you the *magnitude* of the Coriolis force at a given latitude. 
When have a bus traveling at 50 km/h at latitude of 40° then this acceleration is [a small fraction of the gravitational acceleration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%287.29*10%5E%28-5%29sec%5E-1%29*50km/h*sin%2840%C2%B0%29).

When you want to know in which *direction* the force is pointing, you have to consider the cross-product again: when you're traveling from the north to the south (like in the picture), then $\vec \omega \times \vec v$ points *into* the screen and $-\vec \omega \times \vec v$ *out of the screen*, so a bus traveling south would be accelerated to the west. When you travel from the east to the west, then the resultant vector points to the north. Or simply put: on the northern hemisphere the Coriolis force deflects always to the *right*.

For a more intuitive approach why the Coriolis force points to the north when traveling west, see the answer to [this question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43124/is-there-an-intuitive-explanation-for-the-southward-force-caused-by-the-coriolis?rq=1)

(Note that I considered only motion parallel to the earths surface. If you want to drop a ball from a tower it's a bit different.)

> Also, can I use $ω=\frac{2π}{T}$ to calculate $ω$? Would T be the seconds in a day?

In principle yes. However, if you [do it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2pi%20radians%20/%20%2824*3600%29%20sec), then you will get an angular velocity which is slightly lower than the value you get from websites [like this.](http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/models/constants.html) This has to do with the difference between the sidereal and solar day, but I won't go into any details here. (And I think if you only need the first 2 digits it doesn't matter. ^^)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how this answer takes the direction of the force into account. Certainly if the velocity is due north-south (with respect to the surface of the earth), then $\varphi = \pi - \theta$. But what if the velocity is due east-west? Isn't $\theta$ (the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{\omega}$ always $\pi/2$ in this case? But that would mean that the Coriolis force on an east-west motion is independent of latitude, which is clearly wrong. Can you tell me why I'm confused?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the coordinated System $(\hat{e}_{E}, \hat{e}_{N}, \hat{e}_{r})$
Where

$\hat{e}_{E}$ := unit vector pointing East

$\hat{e}_{N}$ := unit vector pointing North

$\hat{e}_{r}$ := unit vector normal to the surface of the Earth at the point of longitude

In the inertial reference frame $$\boldsymbol{\omega} = \omega \hspace{1mm} \hat{e}_{N}$$

Then from the plane of the Earth's rotation $\hat{e}_{N}$ and $\hat{e}_{r}$ are rotated by and angle $\phi$

$$\begin{bmatrix}\omega_{r}  \\\omega_{N} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\phi & \sin\phi\\-\sin\phi &\cos\phi \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \omega\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\overline{v}$ be the velocity of the mass point in the non-inertial reference frame rotating at the point of longitude. Then
$$a_{Coriolis} = -2(\omega\times \overline{v}) = -2(0,\omega\cos\phi, \omega\sin\phi)\times(\overline{v}_{E},\overline{v}_{N},\overline{v}_{r}) = $$

$$-2\omega[(\overline{v}_{r}\cos\phi-\overline{v}_{N}sin\phi)\hat{e}_{E}+\hspace{1mm}\overline{v}_{E}\hspace{1mm}sin\phi\hspace{1mm}\hat{e}_{N}-\cos\phi\hspace{1mm}\overline{v}_{E}\hspace{1mm}\hat{e}_{r}]$$